# 20.04 Display flickering issue

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kubuntu, multiple-monitors, kde

I today upgraded my 18.04 Kubuntu kde plasma laptop to 20.04.1.
It's a dell XPS 13 9370.

Everything was fine, working great even. The performance was snappier, felt better than what I was used to and I was not looking back.

I however rebooted after working a few hours and my laptop screen has not been the same since.
Flickering and strange artifacting, after entering the bios the pixels will partially still show the bios option screen when booting into the OS etc..

Secondary 4k monitor is completely fine, it's just the laptop itself that shows weird behaviour and tearing/artifacting. Also a sort of burn in effect that happens. [burn in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JGlY.jpg)

I suspect this is something driver-related and after the reboot it stopped loading in the working ~drivers~ from 18.04, but I have no idea where to start.

[biosscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHwhQ.jpg)

[both screens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4iug.jpg)

[laptop screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oo4Qk.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I am no longer linking this to the upgrade but to it being a weird coincidence. This is a hardware failure as far as I'm concerned now.